# how to get user's phone number in Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to get user's phone number in Cloud Functions when a new user is signed up.
For example here

`exports.userSignedUp  = functions.auth.user().onCreate(function(event) {})`

that event returns many data about the user but I didn't see any phone number in case user signed up using their phone number.

Comment: [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#phoneNumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns phone number when we use phone number sign in! Else you need to respective permission for google signin or other third party signin

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the answer in documents, but then I looked into the [source code].[1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/user-import-builder.ts)

so it actually does return phone number data as `phoneNumber`